# How can I optimize this mysql query to find maximum simultaneous calls?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to calculate maximum simultaneous calls. My query, which I *believe* to be accurate, takes way too long given ~250,000 rows. The cdrs table looks like this:

```
+---------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | bigint(20) unsigned   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| CallType      | varchar(32)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| StartTime     | datetime              | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| StopTime      | datetime              | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| CallDuration  | float(10,5)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| BillDuration  | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| CallMinimum   | tinyint(3) unsigned   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| CallIncrement | tinyint(3) unsigned   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| BasePrice     | float(12,9)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| CallPrice     | float(12,9)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| TransactionId | varchar(20)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| CustomerIP    | varchar(15)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ANI           | varchar(20)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ANIState      | varchar(10)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| DNIS          | varchar(20)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| LRN           | varchar(20)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| DNISState     | varchar(10)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| DNISLATA      | varchar(10)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| DNISOCN       | varchar(10)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| OrigTier      | varchar(10)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| TermRateDeck  | varchar(20)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have the following indexes:

```
+-------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name        | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| cdrs  |          0 | PRIMARY         |            1 | id          | A         |      269622 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| cdrs  |          1 | id              |            1 | id          | A         |      269622 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| cdrs  |          1 | call_time_index |            1 | StartTime   | A         |      269622 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| cdrs  |          1 | call_time_index |            2 | StopTime    | A         |      269622 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

The query I am running is this:

```
SELECT MAX(cnt) AS max_channels FROM
  (SELECT cl1.StartTime, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM cdrs cl1
    INNER JOIN cdrs cl2
    ON cl1.StartTime
    BETWEEN cl2.StartTime  AND cl2.StopTime
    GROUP BY cl1.id)
  AS counts;
```

---

It seems like I might have to chunk this data for each day and store the results in a separate table like `simultaneous_calls`.

Comment: How long does it take?  How long do you want it to take?  Also, can you show us an EXPLAIN of the query?

Comment: I don't think it matters, but you don't need to select `cl1.StartTime` in the subquery. All you need is `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: @AndyLester It's coming up on three hours now haha. I was going to do an EXPLAIN but didn't want to slow it down any more.

Comment: No need to EXPLAIN, it will tell you that is doing 62.500 BILLION comparisons, most likely also storing the temporary table on disk in between.

I think you need to find another way, perhaps not even SQL, to find this than a self join on a large table.

Comment: @Jason, you probably know a lot more about money than me. Even so, I find the choice of FLOAT as opposed to DECIMAL decidedly odd!

Comment: @Strawberry haha yea I suppose all those floats should be decimal.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you want to know not only the maximum simultaneous calls, but *when* that happened.

I would create a table containing the timestamp of every individual minute

```
CREATE TABLE times (ts DATETIME UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO times (ts) VALUES ('2014-05-14 00:00:00');
. . . until 1440 rows, one for each minute .  . .
```

Then join that to the calls.

```
SELECT ts, COUNT(*) AS count FROM times 
JOIN cdrs ON times.ts BETWEEN cdrs.starttime AND cdrs.stoptime 
GROUP BY ts ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Here's the result in my test (MySQL 5.6.17 on a Linux VM running on a Macbook Pro):

```
+---------------------+----------+
| ts                  | count(*) |
+---------------------+----------+
| 2014-05-14 10:59:00 |     1001 |
+---------------------+----------+
1 row in set (1 min 3.90 sec)
```

This achieves several goals:

- Reduces the number of rows examined by two orders of magnitude.
- Reduces the execution time from 3 hours+ to about 1 minute.
- Also returns the actual timestamp when the highest count was found.

Here's the EXPLAIN for my query:

```
explain select ts, count(*) from times join cdrs on times.ts between cdrs.starttime and cdrs.stoptime group by ts order by count(*) desc limit 1;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                          |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | times | index | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 5       | NULL |   1440 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cdrs  | ALL   | starttime     | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 260727 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x4) |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Notice the figures in the **rows** column, and compare to the EXPLAIN of your original query. You can estimate the total number of rows examined by multiplying these together (but that gets more complicated if your query is anything other than SIMPLE).

Comment: This looks promising. Although, it seems strange to create a times table. Would I have to continually insert new rows for every minute? Also, it seems to me that this would consider calls on the same minute as simultaneous, is that right? Obviously a call could _end_ at the beginning of the minute and another could _start_ at the end of the minute.

Comment: @Jason: this also doesn't take into account the edge cases of calls less than one minute in duration, that start and stop within the same minute (don't cross a boundary). But, those may be edge cases that can be disregarded, and this may be a close enough approximation. (I think the real performance boost here is that this checking only one day. You could also test the query (with the correlated subquery) in my answer adding a predicate `cl1.StartTime >= '2014-05-14' AND cl1.StartTime <  '2014-05-14' + INTERVAL 1 DAY`, to get an equivalent result.

Answer (score 1):

The inline view isn't strictly necessary. (You're right about a lot of time to run the EXPLAIN on the query with the inline view, the EXPLAIN will materialize the inline view (i.e. run the inline view query and populate the derived table), and then give an EXPLAIN on the outer query.

Note that this query will return an equivalent result:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS max_channels
  FROM cdrs cl1
  JOIN cdrs cl2
    ON cl1.StartTime BETWEEN cl2.StartTime  AND cl2.StopTime
 GROUP BY cl1.id
 ORDER BY max_channels DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

Though it still has to do all the work, and probably doesn't perform any better; the EXPLAIN should run a lot faster. (We expect to see "Using temporary; Using filesort" in the Extra column.)

---

The number of rows in the resultset is going to be the number of rows in the table (~250,000 rows), and those are going to need to be sorted, so that's going to be some time there. The bigger issue (my gut is telling me) is that join operation.

I'm wondering if the EXPLAIN (or performance) would be any different if you swapped the cl1 and cl2 in the predicate, i.e.

```
ON cl2.StartTime BETWEEN cl1.StartTime AND cl1.StopTime
```

I'm thinking that, just because I'd be tempted to try a correlated subquery. That's ~250,000 executions, and that's not likely going to be any faster...

```
SELECT ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM cdrs cl2
          WHERE cl2.StartTime BETWEEN cl1.StartTime AND cl1.StopTime
       ) AS max_channels
     , cl1.StartTime
  FROM cdrs cl1
 ORDER BY max_channels DESC
 LIMIT 11
```

You could run an EXPLAIN on that, we're still going to see a "Using temporary; Using filesort", and it will also show the "dependent subquery"...

---

Obviously, adding a predicate on the cl1 table to cut down the number of rows to be returned (for example, checking only the past 15 days); that should speed things up, but it doesn't get you the answer you want.

```
WHERE cl1.StartTime > NOW() - INTERVAL 15 DAY
```

(None of my musings here are sure-fire answers to your question, or solutions to the performance issue; they're just musings.)

Comment: Your musings are very much appreciated ;) I got the following error on your second query: `Unknown column 'cl1.EndTime' in 'where clause'`

Comment: @Jason: entirely my bad. The column name in your query is `StopTime`, I mis-typed that as `EndTime` everywhere in my answer. I will revise my answer so the column name matches your column name.

Comment: Ha I should have caught that. Here is the [result of the EXPLAIN](http://hastebin.com/lobilipixe.sm).

Comment: @Jason: the EXPLAIN for the second query shows that the query is going to be satisfied from the covering index, but, that's still 269,622 executions of the subquery. (The performance is simple math:  however long it takes to do a `COUNT(1)` query using the covering index, times 269,622 executions of that.

Comment: I'm doing some more testing and it seems like your second query is quite efficient. Especially when I include the WHERE clause like your example... last 10 days takes ~6 sec. What do you mean by `COUNT(1)`?

Comment: @Jason: The performance of that query is going to fairly linear, based on the number of rows returned for `cl1`; each row returned is going to execute the correlated subquery in the SELECT line, the more rows returned, the more subquery executions. (The nonlinear part of the performance is the sort operation on the rows).  I said `COUNT(1)`, i was referring to that subquery that returns the count; the count aggregate function increments the value by one for every row where the expression is non-null, so `COUNT(*)` is equivalent to `COUNT(1)`, is equivalent to `COUNT('foo')`, etc.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. It looks like your query is about 3x faster than my original query, so thank you! _But_, I think I might have to run a daily cron to calculate the previous day's simultaneous calls (~1 sec) and store the results in a simultaneous_calls table. It's been an hour I think trying to process a query for 90 days.

Comment: I don't think this query was accurate for me. I ran it for the last 90 days and it came back with [this result](http://hastebin.com/emigeruhap.1c). There were 2772 calls on March 28th, at a glance it does not look like there were 1351 simultaneous calls.

Comment: @Jason: I think you are right, the logic isn't right. That last query gets a count of the number of calls (rows) that had a start time somewhere between the start and stop of each call, not the number of calls that were simultaneous. (We'd expect this kind of result if there was a REALLY long call... I think the logic in your original query has the same problem, doesn't it?

Comment: I'm really not sure, I've been googling a bit and have come to [this query](http://hastebin.com/tuyesikeme.sql) which returned a result within ~2 sec.